# python assertRaises don't pass test if function with parameters

Tags: python, tdd

assertRaises give an assertion error with the following code. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
class File_too_small(Exception):
    "Check file size"

def foo(a,b):
    if a<b:
        raise File_too_small
class some_Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertRaises(File_too_small,foo(1,2))
```

The test seems to pass with the following modification though

```
def foo:
    raise File_too_small

def test_foo(self):
    self.assertRaises(File_too_small,foo)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
def test_foo(self):
    with self.assertRaises(File_too_small):
        foo(1, 2)
```

or:

```
def test_foo(self):
    self.assertRaises(File_too_small, foo, 1, 2):
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the callable, not the result, to assertRaises:

```
self.assertRaises(File_too_small, foo, 1, 2)
```

Alternatively use it as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(File_too_small):
    foo(1, 2)
```